# How to know if animate.css animation is completed with addClass in backbone view?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, addclass, jquery-deferred, animate.css

I'm using `animate.css` to put some nice effects to my backbone views.
One of the animations that I'm using is the `flipOutX` when a list item is deleted.

Here is my drop function:

```
drop: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.$el.addClass('animated flipOutX');
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.remove();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Knowing that using `setTimeout` is a really bad idea, do you have any work around to apply this effect?
I'm using the `setTimeout` to be sure the `addClass` effect is completed before effectively removing the view.  Here my problem is the fact that `addClass` is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.$el.addClass('animated flipOutX').promise().done(function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

When functions dealing with visual effects (including .css() and .addClass(), .toggleClass(), and .removeClass()) finish, they return a Deferred/Promise object, which will register a completed event that calls a callback (defined by the function in .done()). The jQuery API website goes into more detail but this is the pattern you should use when you need to defer visual events. You can also get into the queue/dequeue system for more direct control of effects.

Comment: Surely, the promise will already exist at the time an effect finishes, so would "... they return a Deferred/Promise ..." better read "... they resolve a Deferred/Promise ..."? (Plus associated adjustment of the rest of the sentence).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, the view is removed before the animation is animation is executed :(

Comment: My understanding is that `promise()`can only be executed on asynchronous function and `addClass` is not async, am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like, check if animation is finished and then move forward, there are several ways to do it. you can use my below modular functions depending upon one's needs to check if animation or transition is finished.

```
        /*
         *   @support check if animation is finished
         */
    var whichAnimationEvent = function whichAnimationEvent() {
            var t,
                el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

            var animations = {
                "animation": "animationend",
                "OAnimation": "oAnimationEnd",
                "MozAnimation": "animationend",
                "WebkitAnimation": "webkitAnimationEnd"
            }

            for (t in animations) {
                if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                    return animations[t];
                }
            }
        }
        /*
         *   @support check if transition is finished
         */
    var whichTransitionEvent = function whichTransitionEvent() {
            var t,
                el = document.createElement("fakeelement");

            var transitions = {
                "transition": "transitionend",
                "OTransition": "oTransitionEnd",
                "MozTransition": "transitionend",
                "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
            }

            for (t in transitions) {
                if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                    return transitions[t];
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is a example http://codepen.io/yoeman/pen/QGPMQz

Hope this helps!